# Vue 2 Check Element Whether Visible on Viewport

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to research about vue2 and wondering if there is any way that can make it easy to track if elements are visible on viewport or not so that we can do something like slide-in boxes when we scroll down the page. Any npm package or whatsoever that can be suggested? Thanks.

Comment: You might find the answer here to be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47491109/vue-js-transition-to-appear-occur-on-element-entering-viewport

Answer (score 30):

Currently using Vue-observe-visibility (https://github.com/Akryum/vue-observe-visibility) and have not stumbled on any issues yet.

The only thing to consider is that this only triggers when the element enters/exits the page by user scroll, not when it enters/exists because of DOM changes. Looks like it shouldn't be an issue for your use case, based on what you told about it.

Certainly check it out, it's easy to use!

Answer (score 7):

**vue-waypoint** could be an option.

[GitHub](https://github.com/scaccogatto/vue-waypoint)

[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-waypoint)