# Vue.js transition to appear/occur on element entering viewport

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, transition

Firstly please **no jQuery**. *I could do this in jQuery etc.*, the point of the question is to do it without unnecessary dependencies.

The scenario here is I'm creating a single page website with several sections to scroll through. I want to use [Vue.js's transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) to simply fade in once the browser has scrolled to that section. I've managed to make the transitions work with the [appear attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitions-on-Initial-Render) but the problem is this initial render trigger works on elements that are off screen and I want to defer that trigger until when the browser has scroll the element on screen.

I've found a library like [vue-observe-visibility](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-observe-visibility) which would kind of works for what I need but honestly I don't want to create a load of data properties simply for the trigger to change it to true for a v-if statement to trigger the fade in effect. Hopefully that makes some sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

one way, using directives, would be have an on-scroll listener. when the element is in view, then add a class that transitions opacity to 1 (or x-offset). Then once it's in view, destroy the listener.

This makes is easy to add to elements, as you don't need to manage state for each item, just change `<div>` to `<div class="hidden hidden-left" v-infocus="'showElement'">`, for every object you want to do this for.

```js
new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data() {},
  methods: {},
  directives: {
    infocus: {
      isLiteral: true,
      inserted: (el, binding, vnode) => {
        let f = () => {
          let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect()
          let inView = (
            rect.width > 0 &&
            rect.height > 0 &&
            rect.top >= 0 &&
            rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
          )
          if (inView) {
            el.classList.add(binding.value)
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', f)
          }
        }
        window.addEventListener('scroll', f)
        f()
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

div {
  min-height: 120px;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

a {
  color: #42b983;
}
/* the classes */
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hidden-right {
  transform: translate(50px, 0);
}

.hidden-left {
  transform: translate(-50px, 0);
}

.showElement {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.8/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div class="hidden" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden hidden-left" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden hidden-right" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden hidden-left" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden hidden-right" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden hidden-left" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden hidden-right" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden hidden-left" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden hidden-right" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden hidden-left" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden hidden-right" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden hidden-left" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden hidden-right" v-infocus="'showElement'">
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

... only, I wish I could remove the listener when the component is unmounted. I think in a SPA this could cause some listeners to stick around.

Comment: Interesting, couldn't this be restructured a little to have the events be on the element itself and then removed from the element after the first run?