# Find div on scroll using VUE.js

Tags: function, vue.js, scroll, vuejs2

I want to fire a function, when a particular div is visible on the page. Its some where in the middle of my my content. I want to execute a function when I scroll to that div with specific ID/Ref.
I'm new to vue.js, can I do this with Vue.js.

```
<div>Some Big Content</div>
<div ref="myDiv" id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47491109/vue-js-transition-to-appear-occur-on-element-entering-viewport/47494016#47494016   Though not a direct duplicate, the similar principle can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, like @Daniel said, to use a `scroll` event listener that checks the bounding box of the div and checks if it is in the middle of the page, then execute the function

One caveat, this is resource intensive so you'll want a function like `_.throttle` from Lodash to keep it from firing constantly when scrolling.

```
document.body.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(checkBoundingBox, 100))
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using a huge library for a single feature, especially if its not in the original question

Comment: Well, you can implement your own version of `_.throttle` without Lodash, but it gets the point across.